# How to run python scirpt for event handling in st_aggrid package

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I tried as below, but it gives error

```
def handle_click_event(event):
   st.write('Hallo World')
   return JsCode("alert('clicked')")
```

I prepare below function to handle cell click event

```
grid_options = {
    'columnDefs': [
        {'headerName': 'Name', 'field': 'name', 'editable': True},
        {'headerName': 'Age', 'field': 'age'},
        {'headerName': 'City', 'field': 'city'}
    ],
    'onCellClicked': handle_click_event
}
```

This is my gripoptions

```
grid_response = AgGrid(df, gridOptions=grid_options, height=300, width='100%')
```

and creating AgGrid object

but it gives error

I asked ChatGPT, there also no significant results

Is there any methods to run python scipt to handle cell clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works since your example isn't runnable, but seems like you might be able to do:

```
gb.configure_grid_options( onCellClicked = JsCode(“”“function(event) { <your code> }”“”) )
```

(Found this [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/ag-grid-component-with-input-support/8108/375))